# Integrand of a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area, multiple-integral

I'm just learning double integrals, and all the questions I've done so far have defined $f(x,y)$ like so:

Evaluate $\int\int{(2x-y^2)}dA$ over the region R, where R is the region enclosed by the graphs of $y=-x+1$ ; $y=x+1$ and $y=3$.

However, the next exercise doesn't define $f(x,y)$, it says:

Find the area of the plane figure bounded by the curves $y_1=(x-1)^2$ and $y_2 = 4-(x-3)^2$.

I've sketched it out and have my limits for both integrals, but I don't know what my $f(x,y)$ I'm supposed to be integrating is, so all I have at the moment is this:

$$\int_1^3\int_{(x-1)^2}^{4-(x-3)^2}f(x,y)dydx$$

I know that $f(x,y)$ is the "ceiling" of the shape that I'm trying to integrate, but I don't know how to find it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Since you are using a *double* integral to find *area*. The integrand is just $1$. If you were trying to find *volume* (under a surface, $f(x,y)$) over the given planar region, then your integrand would be the equation defining the surface (namely, $f(x,y)$, which, is also equal to $z$, 'the height' of the surface, at $(x,y)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding the area $f(x,y)=1$ and then
$$\int_1^3\int_{(x-1)^2}^{4-(x-3)^2}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \int_1^3\int_{(x-1)^2}^{4-(x-3)^2}\,dy\,dx$$

This is saying add up all the infinitesimal elements of (cartesian) area $dy\,dx$ (imagine little rectangles) over the required region, which is then the area of that region.